# Setting Spring WebServiceTemplate dependency at runtime

Tags: java, spring

I have a WebServiceTemplate bean where the defaultUri value is being injected :

```
<bean id="myTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <property name="defaultUri" value="http://server1/test.asmx" />
</bean>
```

The defaultUri parameter is set at runtime :

```
myTemplate.setDefaultUri(getDefaultUri());

method getDefaultUri() reads from an external location
```

I think it's redundant setting this parameter at startup time, so I think I can just remove :

```
<property name="defaultUri" value="http://server1/test.asmx" />
```

But perhaps there is a reason I'm unaware that it has been setup this way ?

Injecting `defaultUri` at runtime instead of startup time is acceptable if `myTemplate` is utilised after the dependency is set ?

Comment: Why do you need to reconfigure it. Why not simply let a property placeholder replace it at startup.

Comment: @M. Deinum defaultUri is required to be updated at runtime. if I "let a property placeholder replace it at startup" then this means the property is just replaced at startup, and is not updated at runtime ?

Comment: Why do you need to update it at runtime...

Comment: @M.Deinum the endpoint URI(defaultUri) can change at runtime,  this is a business requirement and one I cannot change.